# blazor inclide code blocks glitching @{} errors then {} scope errors

Tags: scope, blazor, inline-code

When I don't use @ and just use {}, the scope breaks.

[image: not using '@{}']

When I use @{} for the inline code, the scope works, but it errors because of the @

[image: using '@{}']

Any suggestions?  Sure looks like a glitch to me.  Go Blazor!

Here's a third screenshot where the brackets aren't breaking scope.
[image]

Comment: For future reference, we like code as text here. Pictures can't be searched by Google.

Comment: code wouldn't show the visual studio errors

Comment: They too should be posted as text, prime search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it actually worked with no brackets.  The brackets were messing with the scope, when I thought they were required for in line code.

[image: no brackets for the win]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with Blazor.

The `var ticket` is scoped by the `{ }` block. The `if(ticket == null)` part is outside that block.

If you had posted the code as text and not as pictures I would have fixed it here.

Comment: That's exactly what was going on.  Why do the brackets not mess with the scope in this instance?.. damn.. I can't add photos here.  I'll add it to the original post.